# PHP 7 deprecation

Tags: php, mysql

I have seen many examples of PHP classes having a single function, and it being called by __construct, and I am fine with that, but before I go hacking into countless lines of PHP 5x code, and breaking them out into a function per class,  is there a way I can reference many functions in the same class?
(I duplicated the same function, and named it differently for the sake of being more simple. 
File1: q.php

```
$host = "x";
$user = "x";
$pass = "x";
$database = "x";

class foo {

    public static function check_mysql($host, $user, $pass, $database) {

        $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

        if (function_exists('mysqli_connect')) {
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_errno());
            }
        }

    }
    public static function Xcheck_mysql($host, $user, $pass, $database) {

        $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

        if (function_exists('mysqli_connect')) {
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_errno());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

File2: r.php

```
require_once('q.php');

$foo->check_mysql($host, $user, $pass, $database);
```

Comment: Those are static methods. You need to access them using the static operator `::` like `foo::check_mysql(...)`. This is exactly how it should have worked with php 5 as well. Nothing php5/7 specific here.

Comment: i domt understand this question - whats depreciated?

Comment: You can have many many functions in each class. You might want to read up on [objects and classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).